# Accessing the Array elements returned by groupBy

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, web

I have used groupBy clause to group by JSON data based on the date -

And here is my output -

```
{30-12-2018: Array(1), 12-01-2019: Array(2)}
  12-01-2019: Array(2)
    0: {representativeid: 21, doctor_name: "Test", products: "Sinarest,Globate -G", quantity: "1,2", Retailername: "Kripa Medicals,Nagashree Medicals", …}
    1: {representativeid: 21, doctor_name: "Pass", products: "Sinarest,Globate -G,Mankind", quantity: "1,2,3", Retailername: "Test Retailer", …}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

30-12-2018: Array(1)
   0: {representativeid: 21, doctor_name: "Test", products: "Sinarest,Globate -G", quantity: "1,2", Retailername: "Test Retailer,Nagashree Medicals,Kapila,Kripa Medicals", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

I want access these data for each date (12th and 13th as per the ex) and want to find the number of representatives and doctors present in perticular date.

Code for groupBy -

```
var grouped1 = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(data, 'date'),clist => 
clist.map(DataBasedonDate => _.omit(DataBasedonDate, 'date')));
                        console.log(grouped1);
```

Also tried stringifying the array to JSON and here is the output -

```
{"12-01-2019":[{"date":"12-01-2019","representativeid":21,"doctor_name":"Test","products":"Sinarest,Globate -G","quantity":"1,2","Retailername":"Kripa Medicals,Nagashree Medicals","Pob":"10,10","locations":"12.9196032,77.6085504","area":"Sirsi"},{"date":"12-01-2019","representativeid":21,"doctor_name":"Pass","products":"Sinarest,Globate -G,Mankind","quantity":"1,2,3","Retailername":"Test Retailer","Pob":"100","locations":"12.9196032,77.6085504","area":"Sirsi"}]}
```

Any help would really appreciated

Comment: If you know the date to be searched, then check whether they are in the same manner as the date which the array is getting sorted. Then all you have to do to get the data for a particular day is by saying `grouped1[date]`. This will return an array on which you can later perform a forEach loop and do whatever you want

Comment: Thanks for the Response @Advaith. Unfortunately logging grouped1[date] saying undefined. 
Tried with grouped1[0]['date'], grouped1[0][0]['date'], And every possible. Didnt work.

Comment: Edited Question with adding Stringifying array content. Please take a look @Advaith. Your help would be appreciated.